# Adding "active" status to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add an "active" class to an image swapping script that I found online. The script works great for what I need to do, but I need to style the thumbnail image of the selected image. I figure adding the "active" will make this easier and need some help doing so.

I'm using the following script:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gallery li img").click(function(){
        $('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
    });
    var imgSwap = [];
     $("#gallery li img").each(function(){
        imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });
    $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="gallery/img_1.jpg" alt="" id="main-img" />
</div>
```

Please let me know if I'm not explaining myself clear enough. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$("#gallery li img").click(function(){
    $('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
});
```

to

```
$("#gallery li img").click(function(){
    $("#gallery li img").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if you found that it answered your question, and/or upvote it.